# Neglecting a line of code in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I am running a large loop to analyze data point-by-point, but now I need to do running averages which I want to be neglected.

```
%In-Flight Tag Averaging Center%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%HPOT DP%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    if PWRLVLCMDGPC(i) == 104 && time(i) > 86200
        if HPOTDP(i) ~= -1 && perf_case_c == -1
            hpotp_if_c(i) = HPOTDP(i) - hpot_pcp_c(i); 
            fun = @(x) mean(x(:));
            hpotp_rep_c = nlfilter( hpotp_if_c,[1 20],fun);
        end
    end
```

As is, the code will get stuck in the `nlfilter`. Can anyone see a way around this?

The final intent would be to do an sliding (moving) average of the hpotp_if_c being calculates so mean(1:20) would be the first point of the vector hpotp_rep_c, mean (2:21) would be the second etc.

I just want to note again that all of these operations need to be done inside of a larger for loop, so these functions don't really work

Comment: what are all those variables? can you post the last values it computes?

Comment: Are you talking about taking a moving average of your `hpotp_if_c` vector? You could look at the [`smooth`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html "documentation") function if you have the curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: @McMa they are very large vector around 7640 values

Comment: @Engineero yes I guess it's really more of a moving average I'll try smooth

Comment: @Engineero turns out I don't have that tool box.

Comment: Then your code is not really getting stuck; `nlfilter` is just too damn slow. Posting an answer with vectorization...

Comment: You might consider exponential smoothing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing ) - that can be implemented easily and performs quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `nlfilter` is not really supported by JIT:

```
fun = @(x) mean(x(:))

a=rand(1,7000);

feature accel on

tic
nlfilter(a,[1,20],fun);
toc

feature accel off

tic
nlfilter(a,[1,20],fun);
toc
```

outputs

```
fun = 

    @(x)mean(x(:))

Elapsed time is 0.764700 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.914575 seconds.
```

That called inside a 1 to 7000 loop will take you around 1.5 hours to compute :(

You can vectorize your whole `for` loop with something like (emphasis in "something like", did not run this code so it might not be copy-pasteable)

```
A=(PWRLVLCMDGPC== 104).*(time > 86200).*(HPOTDP ~= -1).*(perf_case_c == -1);

hpotp_if_c(A) = HPOTDP(A) - hpot_pcp_c(A); 

hpotp_rep_c = nlfilter( hpotp_if_c,[1 20],fun);
```

After all , your old loop was overwriting all values of `hpotp_rep_c` over and over.